# How to show a PNG image with 25% opacity using GDI+? (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+

I am trying to output a PNG image by using GDI+, MFC. I want to output it with 25% opacity. Below is the way to output a PNG image on x=10, y=10:

```
    CDC *pDC =GetDC();
    Graphics graphics(pDC->m_hDC);
    Image image(L"test1.png", FALSE);
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, 10, 10);
```

But I don't know how to make it translucent. Any idea?

Comment: You are asking two different questions: The title suggests, that you somehow want the alpha channel of the image to have any effect, while the question body seems to only want to render the entire image at 25% opacity. Which one do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw the image with alpha blending, declare [`Gdiplus::ImageAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534464(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`Gdiplus::ColorMatrix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534063(v=vs.85).aspx) with required alpha channel:

```
float alpha = 0.25f;
Gdiplus::ColorMatrix matrix =
{
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, alpha, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1
};

Gdiplus::ImageAttributes attrib;
attrib.SetColorMatrix(&matrix);
graphics.DrawImage(&image, 
    Gdiplus::Rect(10, 10, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight()), 
    0, 0, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight(), Gdiplus::UnitPixel, &attrib);
```

See also: [Using a Color Matrix to Transform a Single Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533875(v=vs.85).aspx)

*Note that `GetDC()` is usually not used in MFC. If you do use it, be sure to call `ReleaseDC(pDC)` when `pDC` is no longer needed. Or simply use `CClientDC dc(this)` which has automatic cleanup. If painting is done in `OnPaint` then use `CPaintDC` which also has automatic cleanup:*

```
void CMyWnd::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(dc);
    ...
}
```

Comment: For Windows 8 and above, a (simpler and more efficient) alternative is to create a [layered window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#layered) for the image, and let the system do the heavy lifting.